# How to get formatted display cell value in excel using closedXML?

Tags: excel, closedxml

[image]I would like to get the displayed value in excel, not the rich text, but the formatted display value.

For example, if the value is "7/1/2015", and this cell is with number format:`cell.Style.NumberFormat.Format="d"`, then in excel this number will be displayed as 1.

I would like to get the "1" by using closedXML but with no success. Below are some value I tried:

```
cell.Value = "7/1/2015";
cell.RichText.Text = "7/1/2015";
cell.GetString() = "7/1/2015";
cell.GetFormattedString() = "7/1/2015";
cell.GetValue<string>() = "7/1/2015";
```

Does any one know how to achieve this?
Many thanks!

Comment: What is cell.DataType? It should be DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `NumberFormat.Format`?

ex. `worksheet.Cell(rowCount, 2).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";`

Let me know if this is whatyou're looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Because what I see in excel is the value "1", I would like to get the "1" instead of "7/1/2015"

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found this: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/270

which indicates that closedXML formattedstring is different from Excel's and there won't be a fix.
So I ended up adding my own custom handler for date time values.

Comment: Correct. Because the .NET formatter is used, you would have to use `%d` to get the value you require. But then that would not work in Excel. At the moment you'll have to use another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> To get the display value for an Excel cell, i used this below RichText property rather than using the Cell.Value property (which gives the actual value of the cell without formatting).

```
using cXl = ClosedXML.Excel;

string cellValue, col="A";
int row=1;
cXl.IXLWorksheet ws;

cellValue = ws.Cell(row, col)
              .RichText
              .ToString();
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Please add a comment explain your code and include why your code works as OP need or it is better than other answers posted before you.